# RxJs: Issue getting UI to update observable based on an inherited class

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having a problem getting the UI to update when the html element is bound to the return value of a function that depends on an observable in the base class.

Here is a highly contrived example. The problem is that when the component is loaded and the html element render results in the call to `getColor()` in the component, the member variable `orange` is `null`.

I do see the base `Orange` class's `initialize` get called and the value of `color` being set correctly. However, this does not cause the UI to refresh. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

thanks!!!

```
//--------------------
//app.component.html:
  <div> {{ getColor() }}


//-----------------------
//app.component.ts
export class AppComponent {
  orange: IOrange

  constructor() {
    orange = new navelOrange()
  }

  getColor() {
      orange.getColor();
  }
}

//-------------------
//orange.ts
export class Orange {
  color: Color;

  initialize() {
    // let's say there is a fruit service that we injected
    let orangeColor$ = this.fruitService.getOrangeColor();
    orangeColor$.subscribe( data => this.color = data);
  }  
}

//--------------------
//navelOrange.ts
export class NavelOrange extends Orange{

  constructor() {
    super();
    initialize(); // allows base class to call service to initialize members
  }

  getColor() {
    return this.color; // from base class
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your template correct?

```
{{ getColor{}()  }}
```

I would expect that to fail.  It should be

```
{{ getColor()}}
```

Comment: Yes, it has a `this.` just missed it in my example :)

Comment: Please update it and take some time (possibly even create a codepen, fiddle) to make sure your example is real.  We can't help unless the info is good.

Comment: yes it is `{{ getColor() }}` (another typo in the example). I'll try and get it running in codepen as Nix suggests. thanks